# Can the Java Cassandra 4.x mapper convert an Enum to an int?

Tags: java, cassandra

I've got a really simple enum

```
public enum Axis {
  X, Y, Z;
}
```

I used to use the `EnumOrdinalCodec` 3.x driver to save this into an `int` in the database.  With 4.x I get an error

> The CQL ks.table: [snip] defined in the entity class: [snip] declares type mappings that are not supported by the codec registry:
> Field: axis, Entity Type: [snip].Axis, CQL type: INT

I can't find any annotations that can be used to tell the driver how to map the enum.  The only hook appears to be `MapperResultProducer` which I cannot comprehend nor find examples of.

Is there a better way than manually mapping the enum to its ordinal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was restored starting with Java driver 4.8 - there is a [new `ExtraTypeCodecs` class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/custom_codecs/#using-alternative-codecs-provided-by-the-driver) that contains additional codecs.  You'll need to use codec returned by [function `ExtraTypeCodecs.enumOrdinalsOf(Class)`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/custom_codecs/#mapping-java-enums).  (but see the comment there, that it's better not to use that because number can change if you change your enum incorrectly)